# связь между компонентами одного уровня react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, slick.js

Есть 2 компонента.  1йы компонент это слайдер,который занимает центр экрана .2ой компонент footer это кнопка которая находится внизу экрана и при клике на которую слайдер должен перебрасывать на 1ое фото.Если делать такую кнопку в самом компоненте со слайдером то можно написать такую штуку

`goToFirst = () => {
    this.slider.slickGoTo(this.state.slideIndex);
  };`
и вот вопрос ,можно ли как-то обратиться к этому методу кнопкой из другого компонента или написать такой метод в другом компоненте?Или это плохая практика реакта ,что кнопка которая взаимодействует с элементом находится не в нем самом ,а черт знает где.

Comment: В данном случае вам нужен state. Это может быть либо state родительского компонента - тогда в дочерние элементы надо передавать callback, частности onOnlick для компонента с кнопкой, который будет устанавливать новый state, что приведет к обновлению всего поддерева элементов. В сам слайдер надо передавать номер текущего слайда, и менять этот номер так же через callback в глобальном state. 

Иной подход - это использовать redux, mobx, unstated - state-менеджеры, или же context api.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать 3 компонента. Родитель ( контейнер ) , в нем хранится логика, и слайдер с кнопкой. Логику переключений и проброс организуем в контейнере, и через props передаем наши функции, которые отвечают за переключение
https://codesandbox.io/s/980kyw633y